# Suborders support in SalesForce.com

Tags: opportunity-lineitem

Does order tracking and fulfillment in SalesForce allow an order from a customer to be split for fulfillment into separate parts (sub-orders).

> Example: A customer places an order for 20 widgets to our company. We
>   receive the order and split it into three parts: 5 widgets from
>   supplier A, 7 from supplier B, and 8 from supplier C. Suppliers A and
>   B send their widgets to us (total of 12). We send 10 to customer. We
>   wait for supplier C and when they send their 8 we send the remaining 2
>   from before and the new 8 to the  customer.

In the above scenario two things are interesting: splitting the order into three suppliers (the customer does not really care about this), and then sending the ready widgets in two separate shipments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.  You can either have someone manually create the three suborders or build some custom code to do the split for you.

**Documentation**

- [Webservices API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index.htm) (ERDs and doc referenes)
- [APEX API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index.htm) (Custom Code)

Comment: Can you please point me to the documentation where it is explained how suborders are created?

Comment: There isn't documentation for that per se, but you'll they have general documentation for custom code available.  I've updated my answer to include some to look into